# choose selected option with knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have a combobox that looks like this:

```
<selectdata-bind="options: adaptPoss, optionsText: 'description', click: function(data,event) {$parent.taskChanged(data,event)}">
    </select>
```

now i want to track which element is chosen (To speak in C# the "selectedIndexChanged") 
how is that function called in knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use value binding:

```
<select data-bind="options: adaptPoss, optionsText: 'description', value: selectedIndexChanged, click: function(data,event) {$parent.taskChanged(data,event)}">
    </select>
```

Read documentation at the knockout site: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Also you don't need to have such complex click handler, knockout automatically sends `data` and `event` objects to the function so you could write the following code:

```
<select data-bind="options: adaptPoss, optionsText: 'description', value: selectedIndexChanged, click: $parent.taskChanged"> </select>
```